# Need a little help, I need correct syntax for grep and copy

Tags: grep, find, xargs, cp, cpio

I currently have 3TB of data on a disk with small to medium files in hundreds of folders.
I need to find certain text files witch contain certain words ( more than one word ).
I've already tried grep-ping for them.
This works as it prints the path to every file.
But this is a long list and I'm now looking for a workable way to copy them to another folder.

any ideas ?

Is there some way to put -exec cp -rv /estinationfolder in the syntax and have it copy all results to the folder ?

Comment: You don't mention this in your question: is a file a match if it contains all of the words, or is it a match even if only contains any one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , certainly there is a way.

You can pipe the grep output to copy command and provide required destination directory.

Here is a example,

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "textToSearch" | cpio -pV $destination_path
```

this script will copy files to destination path provided in destination_path variable

Best part with this is, it will copy the files while preserving the full path.

Comment: what will happen, if he files contain spaces? (nothing good). Did you test your answer for special cases like that?